# How to loop through column values from a table and create folders via powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to achieve the following via powershell:

I have a table(TBL_DDL) with 5 columns (CATALOG,SCHEMA,OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_NAME,DDL)

Now, i'm extract data from this table and then trying to create a folder structure by concatenating first 4 columns (CATALOG,SCHEMA,OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_NAME) in C: drive and then exporting the data in DDL column in txt file.

For eg: C:\"CATALOG"\"SCHEMA"\"OBJECT_TYPE"\"OBJECT_NAME"\DDL.txt

I'm trying to achieve this via powershell. Can anyone help me please?

```
$SqlCmd = 'snowsql -c example -d tu_test -s public  -q "select catalog,schema,OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_NAME,DDL from SF_TBL_DDL limit 2"'
$MultiArray = @(Invoke-Expression $SqlCmd)
$dt = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("CATALOG")
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("SCHEMA")

$Output = foreach ($Object in $MultiArray)
        {
        foreach ($SCHEMA in $Object.SCHEMA) 
            {

            $someother = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{CATALOG = $Object.CATALOG; SCHEMA = $SCHEMA}
            $nRow = $dt.NewRow()
            $nRow.CATALOG = $someother.CATALOG
            $nRow.SCHEMA = $someother.SCHEMA
            $dt.Rows.Add($nRow)
            }   
        }
$dt.row.count
```

At the moment, i'm getting 0 rows in $dt. 
Cheers

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried.

Comment: hi. i'm basically new to powershell. I'm basically trying to store the query result in an array and then loop through the result to store values in respective columns in the array. I'm trying something like this:

Comment: Here it is : But it doesn't seem to work                                                            
 $SqlCmd = 'snowsql -c example -d tu_test -s public  -q "select catalog,schema,OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_NAME,DDL from SF_TBL_DDL limit 2"'
$MultiArray = @(Invoke-Expression $SqlCmd)
$dt = New-Object System.Data.Datatable
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("CATALOG")
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("SCHEMA")
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("OBJECT_TYPE")
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("OBJECT_NAME")
[void]$dt.Columns.Add("DDL")
foreach($row in $MultiArray)
{
[void]$dt.Rows.Add($MultiArray)
}
$dt

Comment: Can you update the OP with the code you tried so far?

Comment: Update the code above. Can you please suggest where i'm going wrong? @CodeRunner

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Data.DataTable object the pull your result set and then loop through it to perform the required operation.

Here GetTableValues function will retrieve the table values and then use following cmdlet to create directory and file

```
  New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $dirPath
  New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path $filePath
```

Complete code looks like this

```
function GetTableValues(){
$DBConnectionString = "<Your DB connection string>";
$sqlConn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.sqlConnection $DBConnectionString;
$sqlConn.Open();
$sqlCommand = $sqlConn.CreateCommand();
$sqlCommand.CommandText = "select catalog,[schema],OBJECT_TYPE,OBJECT_NAME,DDL from TBL_DDL"; ##Put your correct query here
$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
$table = New-Object System.Data.DataTable;
$table.Load($result);
$sqlConn.Close();
return $table;
}

    $tableValue = GetTableValues;

    foreach ($Row in $tableValue)
    { 
      $filePath = "C:\" + $Row.catalog.TrimEnd() + "\" + $Row.schema.TrimEnd() + "\" + $Row.OBJECT_TYPE.TrimEnd() + "\" + $Row.OBJECT_NAME.TrimEnd() + "\" + $Row.DDL.TrimEnd() + ".txt" 
      $dirPath = "C:\" + $Row.catalog.TrimEnd() + "\" + $Row.schema.TrimEnd() + "\" + $Row.OBJECT_TYPE.TrimEnd() + "\" + $Row.OBJECT_NAME.TrimEnd()  
      New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Path $dirPath  ##Creates directory
      New-Item -ItemType "file" -Path $filePath  ##Creates file in $dirPath directory   
    }
```

This works perfectly fine for me.